# Generating PINS - guarding, limiting and fastest way

Tags: javascript, c#, oracle

My task for today is to generate a PIN. A four digit pin. It has to be random. Are there limitations to doing it and doing it the way I plan? I understand humans can never create something TRULY random but hey who we have to try.

I am currently generating it in client (JS), then passing to the Model (C#) and this is injected to the DB (Oracle). The only safeguards I can think of so far is either generate from 0001 > onwards to anything less than 10000 so 9999 will be the highest number. Anything that is returned that is between these two numbers as long as it has not been used before in my logic is random - we also know we have to check the db to see if the PIN already exists IF NOT then generate it.

I guess I can:

```
onGen() { 
    //generate pin
    var pin = characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
    //check db if pin exists
    const exists = checkDB('select pin from pins where pin =' + pin + ';')
    //if pin exist generate again
    if(exists) pin = characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
    //also should I put my login of 0001 > and < 10000 in the SELECT or js?
    if pin > 0000 return pin
    //or this
    checkDB('select pin from pins where pin =' + pin + 'AND pin > 0001 and pin < 10000;')
}
```

Comment: Don't use `Math.random` to generate secure random numbers. Apparently `Crypto.getRandomValues()` can get you secure random numbers.

Comment: Also your javascript has a way to see whether a pin exists? So anyone looking at that webpage can see what pins exist? Surely that's a massive gaping security hole?

Comment: **Also**, if you pin exists you generate another, but you only do that once. What if that second pin you generated also exists?

Comment: Never mind that, `checkDB` lets the user execute any arbitrary SQL against your database? What on earth? So someone looking at your web page can just delete all pins? Or dump all pins? Or do anything to any other table? Set themselves as admin maybe? Holy mother of cows.

Comment: Create all XXXX combinaisons in DB and then attrib each on demand then switch it to "inUse = true" on  demand, no duplicate and unique use

Comment: Does the PIN need to be unique?  Bank PIN codes are not.

Comment: Thanks @canton7 Ok so that Crypto package will generate more secure random numbers . I can shorten this to 4. It's not a public website so you can't do the injectiony stuff you are meaning and behind a login. We only gen pin only on call so only 1 pin returned. Thanks for the first suggestions though.

Comment: @bZezzz Thanks I guess this is probably the safest and neat way. It gets created in the DB and lives there, is unique and is called on demand. But I may be safe if I generate on the C# layer too - I can one liner LINQ check if exists IF NOT generate and send off to db. Yes or no to this idea?

Comment: @jason.kaisersmith the uniqueness here only is to ensure any new PIN generated mustn't already exist in DB. I think the bank design is different and pins are unique to each customers OWN future or previous PIN - maybe. But not unique between different customers as we know pins can match.

Comment: @stackymackyobroedar For me, YES.

Comment: Thanks @bZezzz. Also while we are on it Random() class in C# is better than Math.Random in JS but maybe close to if not the same as random and secure as the Crypto browser library. Like with everything there's a few remarks "The chosen numbers are not completely random because a mathematical algorithm is used to select them, but they are sufficiently random for practical purposes" D. E. Knuth. , 97.